# Spring Integration Gateway exiting "due to an exception" and not receiving reply after error is handled

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Hey i'm sending messages out to an http endpoint and since i'll have to trigger an error flow on selective failures, i'm sending the message through a gateway before eventually routing it through an http outbound gateway.

```
@MessagingGateway(errorChannel="invocationFailureChannel")
public interface Invocator {
    @Gateway(requestChannel="invocationChannel")
    public Boolean invokeService(Message<String> invocation);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorHandlingFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from("invocationFailureChannel")
            .transform("payload.getFailedMessage()")
            .handle(new GenericHandler<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object handle(Object payload, Map<String, Object> headers) {
                    //Do Stuff
                    return false;
                }
            })
            .get();
}
```

The reply from the error channel is supposed to ripple back to the bean that's actually invoking the gateway right? But i get this weird exception:

> o.s.m.c.GenericMessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel - Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to an exception while sending the request message

I tried setting a timeout on both the request and reply, but that didn't really help. I tried to put an try-catch on the code that's calling the gateway, but i didn't get an error there either.

I even tried an example identical to the one shown in:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mF2uq4DnVCg

I have no idea why it isn't working for me. I get the same error even in a sample example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the gateway sends the error to the error channel, it has a new 'replyChannel` header; the old one is "spent" - it was used when the gateway received the error.

This line...

```
.transform("payload.getFailedMessage()")
```

is messing things up because transformers that return a message overwrite the headers, so the new reply channel gets replaced with the spent one.

You can use

```
.transform("payload.failedMessage.payload")
```

and the framework will take care of maintaining the headers. If you need access to the `failedMessage` headers, you will need a custom transformer, and you need to be sure to retain the "new" `replyChannel` header.

Or, you can copy individual headers from the failed message with a header enricher - `.enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpression("foo", "payload.failedMessage.headers['foo']"))` before the `.transform()`.

Comment: So `payload.failedMessage.payload` is like a trick to use the regular transformer behavior to map the exception message headers onto the failed message right? Does this also hold good when I have an expression evaluating advice on an outbound adapter instead of an error channel on the regular gateway though? Will the successChannel and failurechannel get references to the new replychannel in the header?

Comment: With the advice, there is no "new" `replyChannel` yet - that only happens when the exception is thrown to the gateway, which constructs an `ErrorMessage` with the reply channel for the error flow. If the advice traps the exception, you'll never get a new replyChannel (and the error flow won't be invoked at all). If the advice throws an exception (and there's an `error-channel`), it will happen then, after the advice has done its work.

Comment: Yes, with a transformer that does __not__ return a message, the framework takes the correct action. It's just a convention that when a transformer returns a `Message<?>` the assumption is that the transformer has taken full responsibility.

Comment: Oh so if I have an advice I can just do `transform("payload.failedMessage")` on the failure channel and it'll ripple back to the gateway right? Awesome, thanks.

Comment: Yes, in that case, the `failedMessage`'s `replyChannel` has not been used yet. It's only a problem on the gateway error flow.